# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS started lagging

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I had Asus A555L series laptop whose configurations are as follows:

**Processor:** Intel® Core™ i3-5010U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4

**RAM:** 4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz

**Hard-disk:** 1TB ATA disk

I am running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as dual boot. Every time I boot into Ubuntu OS, I had to mount my both HDD partitions (I have two HDD partitions other than that of where Windows 10 OS is installed). As I am a developer, when I run few softwares like Eclipse, VS Code, and Chrome, laptop starts lagging. I have checked disk, CPU, and IO usage using **top** and **iotop** commands and found that sometimes IO increases to nearby 80-90% where as sometimes CPU reaches 80-90%. But had never seen RAM usage more than 10%. What makes IO and CPU usage increase to such high levels? How to stop my laptop from lagging?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off fast boot options from Windows power options. Then you don't have to mount your partitions again.